# Two '=' in Makefile variable assignment

Tags: makefile

What does

```
FOO := BAR=$(BAZ)
```

mean in a Makefile? It is the second '=' I'm curious about.

Comment: Note that you can check the value of `FOO` after assignment using something like `$(info FOO=[$(FOO)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `=` is part of the data being assigned.  Given that the `:=` signifies assignment to a simply expanded variable, everything appearing after it is expanded at the time that the assignment is processed, and the result is the value of the variable. That will depend on the value of variable `BAZ` at that time, but for example, given this makefile:

```
BAZ = 42
FOO := BAR=$(BAZ)
BAZ = 37

all:
        @echo "$(FOO)"
```

The output of the command `make all` will be

```
BAR=42
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample assigns `FOO` to expand to the string `BAR=$(BAZ)`.